Is this a violation of ISO 27001:2020 A 8.31?
I got given a task. To write a new job, that emails users about their expired media items. During testing, I had to run the job on the staging server.
The manager got an email, due to the queue worker running old jobs, which was associated with the managers email.
I then got fired due to the manager and hundreds of employees being emailed about media items that weren't even theirs.
Am I at fault? Why? Surely this is the business' problem for having real data on a testing environment? Bare in mind, I'm less than 2 months into this role.

What's your actual goal? You know as well as we know you're not going to get your job back even if everyone on the Internet says you were right.

@PhilipKendall I want to know if I'm in the wrong genuinely.. and to understand if they've broken ISO compliance by having real data on a test environment?

If nothing else, the ISO question is off-topic here. If you want to ask it somewhere else, please specify exactly which ISO standard you believe is being broken because I'm sure it's not, for instance, a violation of ISO 9462:2023.

I’m voting to close this question because you've cross posted it on Law, I'm not sure if it's on topic there or not but I'm reasonably sure it's not on topic here, we don't adjudicate ISO27001 questions here.

There is no ISO 27001:2020. There is 2013 and 2022. At any rate, you were fired (presumably) for initiating an action that caused a large problem for the company without checking what the consequences of that action would be. Worst case for them, they have a finding in their next surveillance audit. Best case for you, you learn from this and are more careful next time.

@JoshHallow, Even if someone else did something wrong, you were sloppy yourself. Two wrongs don't make a right. And yes, your employer was a dick for firing you. But hopefully, you can take this experience and learn something from it for your next job.

“Am I at fault? Why?” - If you wrote the task, and it erroneously sent emails, it does indeed sound like it’s “your fault” the task sent those emails erroneously. Even if it is a violation. It doesn’t change the fact the task erroneously sent emails, presumably, more than a few emails of hundreds of employees received emails.

Most reasonable managers would probably give you a warning instead of firing you in this case. However, it is still possible for some managers to fire employees in this situation. The regulations or policy for firing employees are different from one company to another. It is not illegal to fire employees in this scenario.

It sure sounds like it.  You ran the job that resulted in emails being sent out to real email addresses.  You were fired for sending those emails.  I am unsure of why one would be confused.
Typically, when testing an email bot of such, one would use a small data set.  One should limit the both the data that causes the email and those emails under consideration.
Once such a bot works on a very small set of data, then you can escalate it to a slightly larger set.  The goal here is to limit the amount of bad data that can go out until all kinks are worked out.
Limiting the data to be examined would have been helpful.  There is probably no need to send out emails for licenses that expired a year or two and more in the past.

I didn't run the jobs, they were backlogged.

Could this also be a violation of ISO 27001:2022 A 8.31? Separation of Development, Test and Production Environments

It seems you're trying to pick a fight with your former employer here. I suggest that's a bad idea.

@PhilipKendall how? I'm trying to get to the root answer.. you seem to be denying me that ability.

@JoshHallow  Agree the question as worded is off topic.  But regarding your general issue as to what you did wrong, this is the correct answer.  Additionally, in a testing environment I would expect outdated data.  As such, I wouldn't want people to get emails when I'm testing.   Considering this, I would have ALL emails setup to send to a hardcoded email address.  Either a test mailbox or my own if I want to risk flooding it.

@JoshHallow - If it is a violation? What do you hope to have happen? It doesn’t appear that  ISO 27001 has much regulatory weight.
